# Tensor flow shuffle a tensor for batch gradient

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, shuffle

To whom it may concern,

I am pretty new to tensorflow. I am trying to solve the famous MNIST problem for CNN. But i have encountered difficulty when i have to resuffle the x_training data (which is a [40000, 28, 28, 1] shape data.

my code is as below:

```
x_train_final = tf.reshape(x_train_final, [-1, image_width, image_width, 1])

x_train_final = tf.cast(x_train_final, dtype=tf.float32)

perm = np.arange(num_training_example).astype(np.int32)
np.random.shuffle(perm)

x_train_final = x_train_final[perm]
```

Below errors happened:

ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_1371' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [40000,28,28,1], [1,40000], [1,40000], [1].

Anyone can advise how can i work around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to make use of scikit's [shuffle](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html) function.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
x_train_final = shuffle(x_train_final)
```

Also, you can pass in multiple arrays and `shuffle` function will reorganize(shuffle) the data in those multiple arrays maintaining same shuffling order in all those arrays. So with that, you can even pass in your label dataset as well.
Ex:

```
X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this method, below error has occurred. 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'int'

Comment: I would suggest you not to convert data as part of tensorflow computation graph. Define the layers, operations in tensorflow and supply image data in numpy format.